# how to read a *.file

Tags: c#

I am having a problem in reading 20110531.file ,

1) First I am creating a text file 20110531.txt.

2) I am compressing it into a zip format called 20110531.zip .

3) Now when i unzip the file its not creating a text file called 20110531.txt else its creating a file without format called 20110531 not a txt format .

4) When i am trying the file to open with notepad its fine , but my code reads only text file .

5)the code i use to read text file

My code is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Path1 = (string)(Application.StartupPath + "\\TEMP\\futures" + 
                   "\\" + name_futures);
    StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(Path1);
    string str = reader1.ReadToEnd();
    reader1.Close();
    reader1.Dispose();
}
```

5)my code reads only text file can anyone please say me what i should change in my code to read 20110531

Thanks in Advance

Comment: my code is       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                         {
                            string Path1 = (string)(Application.StartupPath + "\\TEMP\\futures" + "\\" + name_futures);
                            StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(Path1);
                            string str = reader1.ReadToEnd();
                            reader1.Close();
                            reader1.Dispose();
                         }

Comment: you can edit your question...

Comment: what is name_futures, what is in it? do you miss there ".txt" ?

Comment: Your problem seems to be the filename used to unzip... and that code is missing.

Answer (score 2):

IF you can give us some code, we can be more specific..

tutorials for this question:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/filestream-open-file/

http://www.csharp-examples.net/filestream-read-file/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

hope it will help you..

Comment: i edited my question pls say there

Answer (score 2):

I would call

```
string str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path1);
```

to read all text. [See this MSDN reference article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx).

Comment: Thanks sir its working i cant vote u because i am not having reputations to vote you i will vote u when i will get reputations thenks

Comment: you can tag ansver as correct:)